# PHP / JS Change values of form dropdown with previous answer with database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

I'm trying to fill a dropdown box in a form with items from a database.
But it only has to fill with the data from a database that is equals to the previous input field.

**Let's pretend that i have a database that looks something like this:**
[image]

and my from looks like this:

```html
    <body>
        <form>
            <input id="nummer">
            <span></span>
         <select name="name">
          <option>name</option>
         </select>
        </form>


    </body>
```

i have already found a way to fill the dropdown boxes with data with this js code but this is without a database:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $nummer = $("select[name='nummer']");
            $name = $("select[name='name']");

            $input = $(this).val();

            $('#nummer').bind('input', function()


                $(this).next().stop(true, true).fadeIn(0).html('[input event fired!]: ' + $(this).val());
                if ($(this).val() == "123")
                {
                    $("select[name='categorie'] option").remove(); 
                    $("<option>Pieter</option>").appendTo($categorie); 
                    $("<option>Steven</option>").appendTo($name); 
                }


            });


        });
```

When i enter 123 in the **number** input field i need the dropdown box filled with **peter and steven**

Is this possible?

Comment: ... and what did you do already?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Yes it is. Why don't you show us what you have done already?

Comment: I've added my js that i have right now i don't now how to continue now @RomeoSierra

Comment: inside bind make an ajax call to your php script (best with a debounce), that queries the database for a matching id and returns the data (the names) as json. Then fill the select with that data.

Answer (score 0):

Program the input field's `onblur` event to look for a dropdown item with the matching value. If found, mark the found dropdown value as `selected`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('#inputfield', 'blur', function(){
        $.ajax(
             //Properties
             //Current value of the input field should be sent to the server
             data:{inputValue:$('#inputfield').val()}, //Use this in where clause in the server
             success:function(){
                 // Populate the data into the dropdown
             }
        ); 
    }
})
```

Here I have outlined what you need to do.

If I fill out the rest, it will be **Me programming for you**. And the necessary information is also not there for me to fill out the rest.